# Contact form 7 plugin wordpress - How to send email of filled values only

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a form that has some optional fields but if a user doesn't fill them out the label of the input will be sent in the email and they will be empty. so for example if a user doesn't enter a city field the email will say City:

Is there a way to set conditionals where if a user doesn't enter optional fields the label wont be sent?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: yes, but.

Long answer: Wpcf7 has events for on send and others that you can hook into to extract and manipulate the data it has at the time.  It's not a well documented aspect of the plug in,  because it's really intended for the developer themselves to use, but you can write add_hook commands into your functions . php file and then use your own functions to change the output.

I think the send hook is called "wpcf7_send" so you can write a function like this:

```
function beforesend($obj) {
    //manipulation of message here
} 
add_hook('wpcf7_send', 'beforesend');
```

It's only a starting point but by exploring a bit you can find the hook names, and class structures you need.